# convert string (array...) to an array php?

Tags: php

```
echo $_POST['var'];

Array(0,Array(0=>;sdfds)),Array(0,Array(1=>;sa;d)),Array(1,Array(0=>;xx;xxx;xxxs))



  $new_str = str_replase(")),A","))|A",$_POST['var']);

  $first_arr =  explode("|",$new_str);


print_r($first_arr);
```

OUPTUT

```
Array
(
[0] => Array(0,Array(0=>;sdfds)) // infact [0] => "Array(0,Array(0=>;sdfds))" not array of array
[1] => Array(0,Array(1=>;sa;d))  // [1] => "Array(0,Array(1=>;sa;d))" not array of array
[2] => Array(1,Array(0=>;xx;xxx;xxxs)) //[2] => "Array(1,Array(0=>;xx;xxx;xxxs))" not array of array
)
```

MY GOAl is to get an array of array some thing like this:

```
Array
  (
  0 => Array(0,Array(0=>";sdfds")),//array of array
  1 => Array(0,Array(1=>";sa;d")),//array of array
  2 => Array(1,Array(0=>";xx;xxx;xxxs"))//array of array
  );
```

How Can I.please help ?
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming HTML,

```
echo nl2br(print_r($x, true));
```

$x = your variable.

This will put newlines in each level. You might also want to do this to preserve spaces:

```
echo str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", nl2br(print_r($x, true)));
```

Comment: @python, your statement doesn't make sense. What do you mean?

Comment: @python I have given you a base to work on, I'm not going to do everything for you or you will never learn. Think about using regular expressions, or even writing your own output function. Why do you want it like this?

Comment: @python, I don't know what you mean, please clarify.